# Use custom dataset for routing

Tags: leaflet, routing

I'm looking to substitute my own dataset with OSM data in Leaflet Routing Machine or another routing tool. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LRM is basically the UI for a routing tool. If you want to manipulate the speeds or weights for the routing you need to go 'down' to the routing tool itself, like GraphHopper is one (note: I'm the author). With these tools you could even modify the street geometry or topology or proprietary street data but also the weights for the routing, like done in [this blog post](https://graphhopper.com/blog/2015/04/08/visualize-and-handle-traffic-information-with-graphhopper-in-real-time-for-cologne-germany-koln/) via traffic data.